# implementation of algorithms and data structures

Tags: data-structures, binary-tree, implementation, binary-search-tree, graph-algorithm

i have successfully implemented several algorithms and data structures.
however, i am not sure how i would implement a graph algorithm, since i would need to represent a graph then. i'm trying to implement algorithms and data structures from introduction to algorithms by cormen et. al.
however, many algorithms take a graph as an input or they take a tree structure as input, which you cannot just provide as text either.
i don't know how to implement dijkstra, bellman-ford, floyd-warshall, kruskal etc.
can i represent any graph as a matrix, even if it is a weighted or directed graph? because i think i can use multidimensional arrays for matrices. i think 0 or 1 could indicate whether there is an edge or not, but i'm not really sure how i would represent any graph using a matrix. and what about a binary tree, if an algorithm take that as an input?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very open-ended question.  The answer depends on the kind of operations that you want to do.

One way to represent a simple graph is an N x N array, where each element represents an edge.  Obviously you only need one triangle and can either ignore the other half or duplicate the information to make lookups easier.

For sparse graphs with a very large number of vertices, you can represent an edge as a node with two links so that it can be on two lists.  Each vertex will have the head of a list of edges linked together.